# How to make copy paste more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba

I use following code to copy and paste within one workbook.

Now I would like to copy 15 columns more from Sheet (1) to Sheet ("Basics"). On Sheet(1) from which I want to copy, all columns are side by side. The problem arise that on Sheet("Basics") where I want to paste **not** all columns are side by side.

Is there are smarter way than mine? If not I would do 15 times the same like in my code below and I assume strongly its not the most efficient way.

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nr_rows As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

With ws
   nr_rows = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
   ws.Range("A2:A" & nr_rows).Copy   
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Basics").Range("E10")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use copy/paste at all.. Just assign the new values directly to the destination range.

Comment: @braX can You make an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Transfer()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nr_rows As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

    With ws
         nr_rows = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
         Worksheets("Basics").Range("E10") = ws.Range("A2:A" & nr_rows)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but thats not working. I have to say that i save all makros in modules so other ones can use these too, if this makes any change. 

And i would have to make the same step also 15 times or?